# copying a pointer created dynamically in array of pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, class, oop, pointers

I am beginner,and i am facing problem when trying to copy one pointer to object in array of pointers..

```
 class Publication
 {
  char title[20];
  int idd;
public:

char* getT()
{
    return title;
}

virtual void getData()
{
    cout<<"Enter Title of Book";
    cin>>title;
    cout<<"Enter ID of Book";
    cin>>idd;
}
virtual void putData()
{

    cout<<"Title of Book : "<<title<<"\n";
    cout<<"ID of Book : "<<idd;
}
};

 class Book:private Publication
  {
    int pages;
  public:
    void getData()
    {
    cout<<"Enter Title of Book";
    cin>>getT();
    cout<<"Enter Pages ";
    cin>>pages;
    }
    void putData()
    {
        cout<<"Title of Book : "<<getT()<<"\n";
        cout<<"No of Pages : "<<pages;
    }
   };
```

Main Function

```
int main()
 {
  Publication *ptrpub[2];
  Book *ptr;

for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
{
    cout<<"Enter Data for Book Object";
    ptr=new Book; 
    ptr->getData();
```

Now within this loop, i want to move that pointer in an array of pointers to publication i.e ptrpub[],where Book class inherits from Publication Privately

```
  ptrpub[i]=ptr;         //'Publication' is an inaccessible base of 'Book'
```

Is there any way to copy them,so i may use ptrpub[i]->putdata() to show all data entered for book object..
And I must keep that relationship between Book and Publication class.

Comment: Use `std::string` and `std::vector` rather than pointers. Those classes know how to copy themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you inherit `Book` from `Publication` privately:

```
class Book:private Publication
```

This means that only `Book`'s implementation is aware that it inherits from `Publication` -- code external to the class does not know this, and so you cannot cast `Book` to `Publication` except from within members of `Book` (or friend members).

You can resolve this by inheriting publicly:

```
class Book:public Publication
```

Comment: But what if I must keep that relationship,is there any other way to do so ?

Comment: @Kashif You keep the relationship, you simply expose that the relationship exists.  In this particular case, I can't see why that would be bad.  (It's fairly rare that you want private inheritance, and this does not look like such a case.)